# Как надо выделять память

Tags: c++

Суть вопроса. Есть класс:

```
class a
{
private:
    int **something;

public:
    a();
    ~a();
};
```

Собственно, как правильно выделять память под двумерный динамический массив? А точнее, где? Некоторые источники указывают на то, что надо не «перегружать» конструктор лишними вычислениями и выделением памяти, а засунуть все в другой метод.

```
a(){something = nullptr;}
void doMemory(){ /* выделение памяти */ }
~a(){if(something != nullptr) /* высвобождаем */);}
```

По моим соображениям "засунуть все в другой метод" интересен, если мы создаем больше объекты и они просто лежат в памяти и ждут своего часа, а когда этот час настает, мы берем объект выделяем под него память и сразу работаем с ним, и он дальше лежит ждет своего часа.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Когда выделять?**

Выделять память нужно в конструкторе, освобождать - в деструкторе. Это - реализация одной из важнейших концепций C++ - RAII (получение ресурса есть инициализация). Если ее нарушить, программа будет либо ненадежной, либо потребуется в каждом методе следить - выделена ли память.

**Выделять крупный блок или матрицу указателей?**

Зависит от размеров и от того, что нужно в дальнейшем с этой матрицей делать.

Если программа работает с гигабайтами данных, и работает не один раз, а в несколько проходов (выделяя и освобождая память между ними), может оказаться, что адресное пространство сильно фрагментировано, и такого длинного куска, как вам нужно - просто нет.

Для 64 бит это не так актуально, но есть на свете и 32 битные системы (в мобильниках и так далее).

Если этим данным предстоит параллельная обработка на многоядерной системе с [NUMA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Uniform_Memory_Access), а вы выделили память крупным блоком, эта самая NUMA вставит вам палки в колеса, когда процессоры полезут не в свои банки памяти за данными - при выделении построчно вероятность такого будет меньше.

**Итого:**
Каждый сценарий обработки данных требует индивидуального выбора способа их хранения.

Answer (score 4):

Начну с конца. Если конструкторов много, то вполне можно вынести общую функциональность в общий метод, и вызывать его в конструкторе (или воспользоваться новой возможностью вызова одного конструктора из другого). Логично и ваше соображение - отложить выделение памяти до того момента, когда она потребуется. Хотя с точки зрения удобства это будет немного хуже - придется все время следить за состоянием, да и удалять, возможно, не в деструкторе, а как только перестанет быть нужной.

Но что касается выделения памяти для `int**`, то оно всегда вызывает у меня вопрос - а надо ли? Зачем вам именно двумерный массив? В конце концов, это тот же одномерный, но с пересчетом индексов. Вам совершенно необходимо обращение к нему как с `[row][col]`? В конце концов, никто не мешает определить оператор `[]`, который будет возвращать указатель на нужную строку, или `operator()(size_t,size_t)` и обращаться к элементу массива как к `a(row,col)`. Но это - мое личное мнение, и тут пусть выскажутся профессионалы. Но когда я вижу

```
something = new int*[rows];
for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    something[i] = new int[cols];
```

"у меня начинает чесаться в самых нескромных местах" (с) :)

Еще раз - это сугубо мое мнение. Но мне кажется, что

```
something = new int[rows*cols];
```

менее, так сказать, error-prone...

Comment: Зато если выделять массив массивов, то он может быть фрагментирован, а с непрерывным куском могут быть проблемы, особенно если планируется изменение размера ( непрерывный может вообще не удастся расширить) , но все зависит от задачи. А т.к. тег с++ то я бы писал вектор векторов лучше...

Answer (score 0):

Мое мнение, определи для двумерного массива свой собственный тип, который будет внутри оперировать низкоуровневыми объектами. Тогда ты сможешь везде его использовать не заботясь о выделении и очистке памяти. RAII - получение ресурса есть инициализация.

```
template<typename T>
class DualArray {
public:
  DualArray(int sizeX, int sizeY)
    : _sizeX(sizeX), _sizeY(sizeY) 
  {
    _buffer = new T[sizeX * sizeY];
  }

  ~DualArray() {
    delete _buffer;
  }

  void set(int x, int y, const T &t) {
    _buffer[y * _sizeX + x] = t;
  }

  T get(int x, int y) const {
    return _buffer[y * _sizeX + x];
  }

private:
  int _sizeX, _sizeY;
  T *_buffer;
};
```